# Do we have to pay for a visa to get into Abu Dhabi during a layover of 16hrs en route to Australia from Norway?

Tags: visas, layovers, australian-citizens, abu-dhabi, norwegian-citizens

Do we have to purchase a Visa into Abu Dhabi during a layover of 16hrs en route to Sydney?

I am Australian and the Wife and Kids hold Norwegian Passports.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.abudhabiairport.ae/en/passenger-guide/transit/visa-requirements

> If you are a citizen of one of the following countries, you will be
> issued with a free-of-charge visit visa upon entry: UK, France, Italy,
> Germany, the Netherlands, Belgium, Luxembourg, Switzerland, Austria,
> Sweden, **Norway**, Denmark, Portugal, Ireland, Greece, Finland, Spain,
> Monaco, Vatican, Iceland, Andorra, San Marino, Liechtenstein, Poland,
> Slovenia, Slovakia, Czech Republic, Lithuania, Hungary, Latvia,
> Estonia, Malta, Cyprus, Croatia, Romania, Bulgaria, United States,
> **Australia**, New Zealand, Japan, Brunei, Singapore, Malaysia and Hong
> Kong.

So, you will be getting a free visit visa. If you are flying via Etihad, you may be getting some additional perks. Confirm with your airline.